# Firebase Analytics - Events Reporting - drill down on event parameters

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated my web app with firebase and enabled analytics.
I am logging an event for **login** as follows

```
analytics.logEvent('login', {'method': 'facebook'})
analytics.logEvent('login', {'method': 'google'})
```

I am able to see the events in the events section.

What I would like to see is the drill down of login events based on method.
i.e

```
Login event: 
method : Facebook   ----   x events
method : Google     ----   y events
```

For the login event, on the edit parameter reporting section, I have added the required parameter (in my case: method) and saved.

After this I could see a new card displaying the following

[image]

But I can't see any other info. Can some one tell me how to get this drill down information.
Is it even possible to get this drill down info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems whatever I have done is the right thing. It is just that the GA shows the drill down only for the data that it received after adding the parameters.
For the previous data it shows as **not set**

Now I am able to see the drill down.